# Overriding generic function error in swift

Tags: swift, generics, overriding

Here's the code:

```
class Test<T> { 
    func foo<S:SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T>(par : S){
        print("foo")
    }
}
class TestInh : Test<Int> { 
    override func foo<S:SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Int>(par : S) { 
        print("loo")
    } 
}
```

And it yells such error:

```
repl.swift:8:19: error: method does not override any method from its superclass
    override func foo<S:SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Int>(par : S) {
    ~~~~~~~~      ^
```

How could I override the method in super class `Test<Int>`?

==================additional=======================

When it comes to the code blow.

```
class Test<T> { 
    func foo(par : T){
        print("foo")
    }
}
class TestInh : Test<Int> { 
    override func foo(par : Int) { 
        print("loo")
    } 
}
```

Everything works fine. Not knowing what happened on `where` statement's appearing.

Comment: I's been said that the two function signatures are different. But the bottom code compiles!!! Which really makes me confused.Even after T is specified their signatures should be considered different too!

Answer (score 6):

When inheriting a non-generic class from a generic one, you should:

- Use `override` with *non*-generic methods; but
- Use *no* `override` with generic ones.

In both cases you can still call `super` implementation of the said method.

Therefore, this should work:

```
class Base<T> {
    func testGeneric<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T>(sequence: S) {
        print("Base \(__FUNCTION__)(sequence: \(sequence.dynamicType))")
    }

    func testNongeneric(element: T) {
        print("Base \(__FUNCTION__)(element: \(element.dynamicType))")
    }
}

class Subclass: Base<Int> {
    func testGeneric<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Int>(sequence: S) {
        super.testGeneric(sequence)
        print("Subclass \(__FUNCTION__)(sequence: \(sequence.dynamicType))")
    }

    override func testNongeneric(element: Int) {
        super.testNongeneric(element)
        print("Subclass \(__FUNCTION__)(element: \(element.dynamicType))")
    }
}
```

Test:

```
let base = Base<Double>()
let subclass = Subclass()

base.testGeneric([])        // Prints: Base testGeneric(sequence: Array<Double>)
subclass.testGeneric([])    // Prints: Base testGeneric(sequence: Array<Int>)
                            //         Subclass testGeneric(sequence: Array<Int>)

base.testNongeneric(0)      // Prints: Base testNongeneric(element: Double)
subclass.testNongeneric(0)  // Prints: Base testNongeneric(element: Int)
                            //         Subclass testNongeneric(element: Int)
```

Comment: That final statement clears it up for me.  Why does the swift compiler not detect that the generic method is overriding its superclass's method?  Why doesn't the override keyword work here?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you received the error is because the method signatures of the `func` and the `override func` are different:

`func foo<S:SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T>(par : S)`

Is not the same as:

`override func foo<S:SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Int>(par : S)`

If inheritance is important to you in this case then you will need to make your subclass a generic entity with a generic type declaration of `T`, and amend your `override func` as so:

```
class Test<T> {

  func foo<S:SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T>(par : S) {
    print("foo")
  }
}

class TestInh<T> : Test<T> {

  override func foo<S:SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T>(par : S) {
    print("loo")
  }
}
```

This should resolve your issue at hand. The reason this resolves is that the method signatures are now the same:

`func foo<S:SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T>(par : S)`

Is the same as:

`override func foo<S:SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T>(par : S)`

Comment: Why the two functions are different? I have specified ```T``` to be ```Int```. Also, if ```T``` is different with ```Int``` no matter whether I specify it, why the second piece of code works fine?

Comment: You have specified `T` to be of type `Int` but that doesn't change the fact that the method signatures themselves differ. `where S.Generator.Element == T` != `where S.Generator.Element == Int`. In order for the compiler to "see" the override the signatures need to be the same.

Comment: Can you explain my second question in my last comment ?