# How to override generic method in generic class in swift?

Tags: swift, generics, overriding

I'm learning swift.
I want to override generic function in generic class.

When I write `override` keyword, compile error happens.

```
class GenericParent<U> {
    func genericFunc<T>(param: T) { print("parent") }
}

class AbsoluteChild: GenericParent<Int> {
    override func genericFunc<T>(param: T) { print("child") }
    // ! Method does not override any method from its superclass (compile error)
}
```

I can omit `override` keyword.
But when I declare the object type as "Parent", the parent's method is called (not the child method). It's not "overriding" literally.

```
class GenericParent<U> {
    func genericFunc<T>(param: T) { print("parent") }
}

class AbsoluteChild: GenericParent<Int> {
    func genericFunc<T>(param: T) { print("child") }
}

var object: GenericParent<Int>
object = AbsoluteChild()
object.genericFunc(1) // print "parent" not "child"

// I can call child's method by casting, but in my developing app, I can't know the type to cast.
(object as! AbsoluteChild).genericFunc(1) // print "child"
```

In this example, I want to get "child" as a result of `object.genericFunc(1)`.
(In other words, I want to "override" the method.)

How can I get this? Are there any workarounds to achieve this?

I know that I can call child's method by casting. But in the actual app I'm developing, I can't know the type to cast because I want to make it polymorphic.

I also read [Overriding generic function error in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585689/overriding-generic-function-error-in-swift) post, but I couldn't solve this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Saying `object` is a `GenericParent<Int>` is only telling the compiler what methods and properties are available. It doesn't change the class from `AbsoluteChild` to `GenericParent<Int>`. `GenericParent<Int>` makes the `genericFunc` method available, but `object` is still an `AbsoluteChild`; which means when you call `genericFunc`, it will call the child's implementation. You cannot cast the object to its parent class to get the parent's implementation.

Comment: Thanks! But when I execute the second sample at playground, `object.genericFunc(1)` prints "parent". It means parent's implementation is called. How can I understand this?

Comment: Oh I see that too. That seems like a bug. You could submit it as a bug to [bugreport.apple.com](https://bugreport.apple.com) or to the [Swift GitHub page](https://github.com/apple)

Comment: This issue is probably same as following issue. https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-103

Comment: As T is generic, the compiler does not know for which type it has to override the function. I would except some kind of 'associatedType' but unfortunately have no computer here to test what I think.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved in Swift 5:

```
class GenericParent<U> {
    func genericFunc<T>(param: T) { print("parent") }
}

class AbsoluteChild: GenericParent<Int> {
    func genericFunc<T>(param: T) { print("child") }
}

var object: GenericParent<Int>
object = AbsoluteChild()
object.genericFunc(1) // print "parent" not "child"

// I can call child's method by casting, but in my developing app, I can't know the type to cast.
(object as! AbsoluteChild).genericFunc(1) // print "child"
```

now triggers an error :

> Overriding declaration requires an 'override' keyword

with :

```
class AbsoluteChild: GenericParent<Int> {
    override func genericFunc<T>(_ param: T) { print("child") }
}
```

the code compiles and prints child both time.